# Indentation in index in Pages document

Tags: pages, text-editor

In my Pages document, I have a passage in my abbreviations list that looks as shown below:

[image]

I'm not satisfied with the display of the first item, because on the second line the word *inscriptions* should be indented, i.e. preceded by a tab.

So I put my cursor at the very end of the first line, just after the character `c` of *Semitic*, and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. Unfortunately, Pages does not interpret the keystroke the way I want, it chooses to push the first line's content backwards rather than pushing the second line's content forward (while the second line stays unindented), so I get something like this:

[image]

How do I achieve the desired result?

**UPDATE** (in answer to Yoan's comment below) : I also tried hitting "<kbd>Tab</kbd>" several times, just before the "i" of *inscriptions*. The four first keystrokes change nothing to the output, and on the fifth the second line is indented correctly but I have an incorrect very long space at the end of the first line :

[image]

Comment: Can you place your cursor before "i" from *inscriptions* and press TAB twice to get the desired result? Just checked and works for me.

Comment: @Yoan doesn't work for me, see my update

Comment: Did you  changed the alignment? seems the last picture has a left alignment, while other(s) are for justified text.

Comment: @Yoan Of course I didn't change the alignment. The aligment is supposed to be justified everywhere. My question could be rephrased as, "why does Pages ignore the justified-alignment requirement in this particular situation". Something is overriding the alignment, obviously.

Comment: You can use Format | Text | Increase List Indent Level or Decrease.., after selecting the second row. In your last picture, *increase* may be moved on the first row?

Comment: @Yoan when I ask Pages to increase the indentation level of just the second row, it increases the identation level of both rows.